# Как сделать сохранение аватарки пользователя AIOGRAM?

Tags: python, aiogram

Как сделать сохранение аватарки пользователя в Telegram через aiogram. Чтобы когда пользователь нажмёт на кнопку "/start", сохранится его аватарка в папке.

Answer (score 2):

Где-то так

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    photos = await message.from_user.get_profile_photos()
    for photo in photos.photos:
        photo[-1].download(destination_file="avatars/sdf.jpg")
```